# T4, how to use EnvDTE get static class

Tags: t4, envdte

how to use EnvDTE get static class

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>

<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>


<#
IServiceProvider hostServiceProvider = Host as IServiceProvider;
EnvDTE.DTE dte = hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
EnvDTE.ProjectItem containingProjectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile);
Project project = containingProjectItem.ContainingProject;
var codes=   project.CodeModel.CodeElements;
foreach (CodeElement code in codes) {
    if (code.Name=="MS") continue;
    if (code.Name=="System") continue;
    if (code.Name=="Microsoft") continue;
    if (code.Name.StartsWith("EnvDTE")) continue;

        try 
        {           
            foreach (CodeElement item in ((CodeNamespace)code).Members) {
                if (item.Kind== vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {  
                    CodeClass cc = (CodeClass)item;
      #>
      <#=cc.Name  #>
      <#
                }
            }            
        } catch {}
} #>
```

this is T4 codes;

It can output the class name,

But it can not determine whether the class is static.

I want to output static class name.

Answer (score 4):

Add references:

```
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE80" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE80" #>
```

Use `CodeClass2` interface, that has `IsShared` property